# Load file in Pig and Transform it to one row with separator

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

i need your help please to output my file loaded in Pig which contains data like this :

```
AAAA,message1
BBBB,message2
CCCC,message3
DDDD,message4
```

and what i need to do is to get an output like this

```
AAAA,message1,BBBB,message2,CCCC,message3,DDDD,message4
```

this output i will use it in other pig udf after..

thank you for your help

Comment: I tried the flatten under the foreach, and many other script that i found but the result is still not what i'm looking for. I need to generate one tuple from all value in the file loaded and put them in one line with comma separator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Input :**

```
AAAA,message1
BBBB,message2
CCCC,message3
DDDD,message4
```

**Pig Script :**

```
A = LOAD 'input.csv'  USING  PigStorage(',') AS (key:chararray,value:chararray);
B = GROUP A ALL;
C = FOREACH B {
    D = ORDER A BY key;
    GENERATE BagToString(D,',');
    }; 
DUMP C;
```

**Output :**

```
(AAAA,message1,BBBB,message2,CCCC,message3,DDDD,message4)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i just changed the bagToString by BagToTuple because i need a tuple to make it such a parameter in my UDF.